# Comfiguring Apache for socket.io and SSL / WSS

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io, wss, proxypass

As the title suggests, I'm trying to get Apache and Socket.io (node.js) to play nicely, especially on SSL. Currently, the client app at *https://www.example.com* uses Socket.io over SSL to connect to the server at [SSL protocol]://socket.example.com/socket.io/?query_stuff*. The connection to wss:// always fails, so Socket.io degrades to https://, which works fine. But I would like to take advantage of the websocket protocol and not rely on polling over http(s).

### Linux & Apache

**Server version:** Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

**Relevant mods:** mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http, mod_proxy_wstunnel, mod_rewrite, mod_ssl

**Iptables:** I have opened ports 80, 443, and 9000.

**VirtualHost:**

I created a virtualhost on *:443 called **socket.example.com**. It's intended purpose is to reverse proxy *[wss,https]://socket.example.com/* to point to the socket.io server running at *http://localhost:9000/*. Here it is, with extraneous bits removed:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName socket.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/socket.io/

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io             [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket     [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           wss://localhost:9000/$1 [P,L]

    ## I have also tried the following RewriteRules: ##
    # RewriteRule /(.*)         http://localhost:9000/$1 [P,L]
    # RewriteRule /(.*)         http://localhost:9000/socket.io/$1 [P,L]

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0001_key-certbot.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/ca-bundle.pem

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

### Success using PHP websockets over SSL

Before switching to node.js for my websocket server, I used the above Apache VirtualHost to successfully route *wss://socket.example.com/ws_daemon.php* to *ws://localhost:9000/ws_daemon.php*. In this scenario I **1.** removed the rewrite rules and **2.** changed the ProxyPass settings to:

```
ProxyPass / ws://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / ws://localhost:9000/
```

But the same logic does not seem to carry over to socket.io.

At this point I've run out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `<Location>` block, you should add the following lines to it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule /socket.io/(.*) ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/$1 [P]
```